# Rails Production App Hangs When Try To Open In Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, rails-postgresql, pg

I have a Rails app that is running on a production VPS Ubuntu server with Unicorn and Nginx server. I've developed app on local machine, where app is working flawless.

But when i tried to open live rails app on FireFox browser, It seems hangs; When i saw production.log , I found following:

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

This is the setting of my database.yml file.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: svschool_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: xxxxxxxx
  password: xxxxxxxx
```

What should i do now to work it well?

Comment: Does it work better with host: 127.0.0.1?

Comment: yes, It works fine in localhost with 127.0.0.1 in my localmachine with development environment.

Comment: I mean works it fine in production with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I use this command rails s -e production in my local machine and i got some errors on controller part, I rectify those errors and deployed to VPS, It works fine now, Thanks.

Comment: So please remove the question.